# What is the best way to load applications on multiple different Android devices?

Tags: android, installation, sideloading

I am running a study which requires me to load my Android app on multiple phones that are different makes and models. The study is specific (we do not want participation from the general public) so I assumed that I could not post the app on the Google Play app store. Is side-loading the app on each phone individually really my best option?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is side-loading the app on each phone individually really my best option?

That depends on your definition of side-loading. Many people consider "anything other than the Play Store" to be side-loading, in which case the answer is "yes".

If you consider side-loading to mean by USB cable, you have alternatives. Put the APK file up on an Web server accessible from the devices, configured to serve up the APK file with the proper MIME type (`application/vnd.android.package-archive`). Then, visit that URL in a Web browser on the device, which will trigger a download and optional install.

Or, use DropBox or similar services that have native Android clients, as they can do much the same thing.